# Why don't the nuget/proget lists use the summary values from the nuspec files?

Tags: nuspec, nugetgallery, proget

I've noticed that when using the summary field as [defined here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference) that the summary nicely shows up in the package management within Visual Studio but they don't show up when looking directly at the package repositories listed below. Why is this? Since it seems to be all of these places not some honor it and some don't there must be a reason.

- http://www.nuget.org/packages
- our private [proget](http://inedo.com/proget/overview) repository

(edit: appears chocolatey prepends the summary to the description)

Comment: The only reason we didn't do this for ProGet is because it wasn't done on NuGet.org :)

Comment: @JohnRasch That's kinda funny. At least there is a reason.

Comment: @JohnRasch I'm not using ProGet [yet?!], but it seems to me that respecting the summary would be a feature you could highlight as an improvement and possibly feed back to nuget as a PR? (if possible)